# Redirect from Jquery to an .aspx file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect

i need to redirect from a Jquery function to a clasic ascx form (no mvc). And also need to pass an id.

Here is my code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = jQuery(".emailListRow");
    jQuery.each(rows, function () {
        var hiddenVal = jQuery(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
        jQuery(this).append("<input type='button' id='btnDetails' value='Details' onClientClick='redirectTo(" + hiddenVal + ")' />");
    });
});

function redirectTo(id) {
    window.location.href = "Forms/Details.aspx?id=" + id;
}
```

This doesnt work... Doesnt throw any errors either.

Help? Maybe i got wrong the parth to the aspx? (This is an ascx located in a folder and within that its another folder (Forms) in which is placed Details.aspx.

Comment: Off-topic: IDs should be _unique_.

Comment: Don't you append several elements with this attribute? `id='btnDetails'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button.onClientClick` is a .NET function, and not something that would work when inserting HTML into the DOM directly.

```
"<input type='button' id='btnDetails' value='Details' onclick='redirectTo(" + hiddenVal + ")' />"
```

Comment: okay at least now i'm getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, still doesnt work...

Comment: That error is usually just a typo somewhere, and the console should point out where exactly the error is located.